# Hot to make the Title Static to make it ignored by system("cls") ? C++

Tags: c++

I want to make the Title Ignored by **system("cls")** everytime when the user start or restart the Calculator the header message must not be cleared and must stay sticky always until the calculator is running.

This is the message that I want to convert to the sticky header in Console:

> Calculator is Running

The Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string Inum;
    cout << "Enter the number to start the calculator" << '\n';
    cin >> Inum;
    bool Decision = true;
    int Inumv_1 = 0;
    if (Inum [0] == '0')
        Decision = false;
    for (int Inumv_2 = 0; Inumv_2 < Inum.length() && Decision; Inumv_2++)
        if (!(Inum [Inumv_2] >= '0' && Inum [Inumv_2] <= '9'))
        {
            Decision = false;
            Inumv_1 = Inumv_2;
            break;
        }
    if (Decision)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "---------------------" << '\n';
        cout << "Calculator is Running" << '\n';
        cout << "---------------------" << '\n';
          char numvalidation[256] = { '\0' };
  double var1, var2;
  var1 != '\0';
  beginning:
    cout << "Enter the First value: ";
  cin >> var1;
  cout << "Enter the second value: ";
  cin >> var2;
  cout << "What do you want to do?" << endl;
  cout << ">> + :Addition" << endl;
  cout << ">> - :Subtraction" << endl;
  cout << ">> * :Multiplication" << endl;
  cout << ">> / :Division" << endl;
  cout << "Please chose one of the option below" << endl;
  char decision;
  cout << "Decision: ";
  cin >> decision;
  system("cls");
  switch (decision) {
  case '+':
    cout << var1 << " + " << var2 << " = " << "" << (var1 + var2) << endl;
    break;
  case '-':
    cout << var1 << " - " << var2 << " = " << "" << (var1 - var2) << endl;
    break;
  case '*':
    cout << var1 << " * " << var2 << " = " << "" << (var1 * var2) << endl;
    break;
  case '/':
    if (var2 == !0)
      cout << var1 << " / " << var2 << " = " << "" << (var1 / var2) << endl;
    else
      cout << "The value you have entered is invalid because you cannot divide any number by zero" << endl;
    break;
  default:
    cout << "Only Number are Allowed, try again ";
    return 0;
  } {
    cout << "Do you want to continue using the Calculator? (Y/N)" << endl;
    char decision2;
    cin >> decision2;
    if (decision2 == 'y' || decision2 == 'Y')
      goto beginning;
       if (decision2 == 'N' || decision2 == 'n')
        cout << "Thank you for using our program" << endl;
      else
      return 0;
  }
    }
    else
        cout << "Invalid Input and contains: [" << Inum [Inumv_1] << "] Calculator can't be started. Try again." << '\n';
        }
```

[image]

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  I suspect that what you really need to do is to replace `system("cls")` with something that only clears *part* of the screen.

Comment: @NateEldredge yes I have solved it and the next issue is how to make it permanently static, so the message will not scroll when using the calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console does not work this way that you can control its scrollbar.
Technically you can use Windows APIs to find `conhost` process window, tamper with its scrollbars... but this will defeat the purpose of console.

One way to achieve approximately what you want is to change real window title by having `system("title Calculator is started");` call.

Another way is to implement your own scrollbar with console symbols. You'll need to use platform-specific console APIs, instead of `cin` / `cout`.

Note that there's no portable way to control console scrolling, moreover, even `system("cls");` is not portable.